# ssh command requires an interactive input

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to ssh into a remote machine and run a script. This script has an interactive confirmation: "Do you want to run it? {Y/N} " kind of thing. How can I say "Y" to this directly through the ssh command?

> out=$(sshpass -p "abc" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root x.x.x.x "./abc.py")

Comment: If that's literally the only string... `out=$(sshpass -p "abc" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root x.x.x.x './abc.py <<<Y')`. By the way, putting extensions on executables is bad form -- you don't run `ls.elf`, and for that same reason you shouldn't run `abc.py`; `.py` extensions are used for Python *modules*, not Python *scripts*. (If you're using distutils to have your `setup.py` generate executable wrappers for your entry points automatically, for example, you'll notice those wrappers don't have any extensions).

Comment: Pretty much all canonical Unix tools let you override these confirmations with flags or similar. Case in point: you're doing it with `ssh`'s host key check right here. Check with `./abc.py` whether it offers such a feature before you try to emulate a human typing in responses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works with sshpass but it definitely works with naked SSH either with key or password based authentication. **If you are in a shell**, you can always provide an input as stdout to the the script using pipes like `echo $INPUT | ./input-script.py|sh` as below -

```
$ ssh -i UAT.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ec2-user 13.222.237.508 "echo hello | ./1.py"
Please enter something: 

you entered hello
```

Python script -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
print "\n"
print "you entered", var
```

Hope this works for you as well!

Answer (score -1):

We should be able to use 'expect' scripting for your problem. You can follow below link for reference - 
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/.

Comment: Yes, `expect` *can* be used, but a good answer on StackOverflow is expected to be self-contained -- to actually solve the OP's problem *on its own*, even if any links contained therein go bad. Consequently, this would be much stronger if it actually showed an example of `expect` being used for the job at hand.